# Рекурсия_Python

Tags: python, рекурсия

Изучаю Python. Объясните как довести  задачу до логического завершения при помощи рекурсии.

**Задача**: Вычислить количество отрицательных чисел в списке [-2, 3, 8, -11, -4, 6]

```
def count(lst):
    if len(lst) == 1:
        return lst[0]
    else:
        return 


print(count([-2, 3, 8, -11, -4, 6]))
```

Вот как решал:
**Вариант 1**:

```
def count(lst):
if len(lst) == 1:
    if lst[0] < 1:
        return 1
    else:
        return 0
else:
    if lst[0] < 1:
        return 1 + count(lst[1:])
    else:
        return count(lst[1:])


print("n = :", count([-2, 3, 8, -11, -4, 6]))
```

**Вариант 2**:

```
def count(lst):
return (1 if lst[0] < 0 else 0) + count(lst[1:]) if lst else 0


print("n = :", count([-2, 3, 8, -11, -4, 6]))
```

Comment: Кажется, вы пытаетесь таким образом решить учебную задачу. Вам не кажется, что это нечестно?

Comment: Я пытаюсь ее решить для себя,  не обязательно выкладывать код. Хотел получить  подсказку в какую сторону идти. Я решил эту задачу при помощи цикла for. А вот рекурсия что то не поддается.

Comment: Два приведенных решения работают, но они как-то мало "отличаются" от простого подсчета, чтобы было "интереснее" можно делить список пополам на чет-нечет `lst[::2]` и `lst[1::2]` и вызывать сумму двух функций (делить до и после середины сложнее, там длину списка надо в слайс подставлять). Когда останется 0, или 1 элемент вернуть соответственно 0, или 0/1 в зависимости от знака.

Comment: Друзья, спасибо всем за помощь в поиске решения. Решил задачу двумя способами (Варианты добавил в шапку.)

Answer (score 0):

Алгоритм:

1. Проверяем нулевой элемент:
   Отрицательный - вернуть 1+функция(остальные элементы)
   Положительный - вернуть функция(остальные элементы).
2. Конечным условием будет `длина массива == 0`, в котором мы возвращаем `0`

Answer (score 0):

любая рекурсия должна обладать

1. условием выхода из рекурсии
2. некоторым изменением входных данных

в данной задачи можно каждый раз функции передавать массив на 1 элемент меньше предыдущего

условием выхода из рекурсии должна быть проверка на пустой массив

ну а возвращать значение равное предыдущему результату + 1 или 0 в зависимости от того положительное или отрицательное число